# Filling fields based on uploaded file from the same model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

This is my model:

```python
class Apks(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(max_length=200, upload_to='files')

    def apk2version(self):
        return subprocess.check_output(['apk2version', self.file.path], stderr=None)
```

The path of uploaded file (by Django admin) and meta information (version field) is in the same SQL table. The table is used by some Android app via some webservice, so I can't easly redesign it.

The version field is filled based on the content of the uploaded file (unpacked from APK file and its manifest by some `apk2version` script)

I tried to override `save` method. Unfortunately, I can't call the `apk2version` script because when the method is called this file is not existing yet.

Is it possible to fill `version` field based on (not yet?) uploaded `file`?

Comment: You can use `post_save` signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

from .... import Apks

def fill_version(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if instance and created:
        instance.version = instance.apk2version()
        instance.save()
post_save.connect(fill_version, sender=Apks)
```

Comment: Almost good. Indeed, the file exists and can be analyzed, but another `instance.save()` makes me "maximum recursion depth exceeded"

Comment: Ok, with the default id (`AutoField`) it does work correctly.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer but checking there if it is created, this must prevent recursion?